# SQLBoiler Eager Loading: how to load specific row?

Tags: sql, go, sqlboiler

I want to execute this eager loading query by SQLBoiler in order to get specific row.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `room_users` WHERE (`room_users`.`room_id` IN (?,?,?,?) AND (room_users.user_id=?, 2));
```

But, I don't know how to write query in SQLBoiler.

My code is here:

```golang
    return entity.Rooms(
        qm.Load(entity.RoomRels.RoomUsers, qm.Where("room_users.user_id=?, 2")),
    ).All(ctx, ur.DB)
```

this code execute this query

```sql
SELECT * FROM `room_users` WHERE (`room_users`.`room_id` IN (?,?,?,?)) AND (room_users.user_id=?, 2);
```

Can anyone teach me how to load specific row by SQLBoiler.

Comment: ORMs... Destroying developer hours since invention.... So the best answer is: Since you can write SQL, you can use that: https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/github.com.vattle.sqlboiler.queries/-/Raw/golang-raw-function-examples.html => See line queries.Raw

Answer (score -1):

this query did work for me

```
 return entity.Rooms(
    qm.Load(qm.Rels(entity.RoomRels.RoomUsers), qm.Where("room_users.user_id=?", 2)),
).All(ctx, ur.DB)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

```
return entity.Rooms(
    qm.Load(qm.Rels(entity.RoomRels.RoomUsers), entity.RoomUsersWhere.UserID.EQ(2)),
).All(ctx, ur.DB)
```